# Export a table of Graphics objects and importing them back

Tags: export, animation

I have a very long code that takes a lot of computation to produce some animations, and some other graphics. I would like to make a presentation notebook including the outputs of this code, but I do not want to copy paste the code because of the time it takes to evaluate the whole thing. I know exporting the outputs as files are the way go, but I would want to import them in such a way that they are again available for me to play around in the Graphics3D interface, I mean. I have animations as tables of Graphics3D[] objects. I do not want to export them as .mov or .avi or .gif because I want to import them an be able to rotate the snapshots. Is there a way to do so, also I outputted the graphics to having no background, but the export changes this to white background, which I dislike.

Comment: Not exactly your question, but just wanted to mention that the way I would probably go about this is duplicating the source notebook, then hiding the code cells by double-clicking on the little bracket extending along the right side of the output cells (and then adding text/presentation cells). Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Also, you could maybe export the graphics as `.wxf` or `.mx` files, which should be Mathematica expressions on import. But it might break when dealing with `Dynamic` functionality—I’m not sure.